# How to move and partially rename files on linux

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I have versioned files which come out of a build pipeline.

```
foo-1.3.4.war
```

and I need to move these files to have the name

```
foo-dev-1.3.4.war
```

How would I go about this?

I was thinking something like 
`mv foo-*.war foo-dev-*.war` but this will only create the files with *.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just bash and commands in most common distributions by default:

`find . -name "foo-*.war" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "other_folder/foo-dev-${1#foo-}"' _ {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me - could also be done with find instead of ls:

```
  #touch foo-1.3.{1..10}.war
  #ls -1
  foo-1.3.10.war
  foo-1.3.1.war
  foo-1.3.2.war
  foo-1.3.3.war
  foo-1.3.4.war
  foo-1.3.5.war
  foo-1.3.6.war
  foo-1.3.7.war
  foo-1.3.8.war
  foo-1.3.9.war

  #for fil in $(ls -1); do 
     filNew=$(echo $fil | sed 's/foo/foo-dev/g');
     mv $fil $filNew;
   done

  #ls -1
  foo-dev-1.3.10.war
  foo-dev-1.3.1.war
  foo-dev-1.3.2.war
  foo-dev-1.3.3.war
  foo-dev-1.3.4.war
  foo-dev-1.3.5.war
  foo-dev-1.3.6.war
  foo-dev-1.3.7.war
  foo-dev-1.3.8.war
  foo-dev-1.3.9.war
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Perl implementation of `rename` program (there is another program called `rename` which is a part of `util-linux` package) like that:

```
$ touch foo-1.3.{1..10}.war
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.1.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.10.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.2.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.3.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.4.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.5.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.6.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.7.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.8.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-1.3.9.war
$ rename 's,^foo,foo-dev,' *
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.1.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.10.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.2.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.3.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.4.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.5.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.6.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.7.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.8.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep  9 19:14 foo-dev--1.3.9.war
```